# Windows app that can stream video over local net with remote browsing

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, video-streaming

What I want:

An app that runs on a windows 7 computer that can stream movies to the other computers in the house. I want to be able to browse the movies on my "server" from the other computers and start streaming.

I'm aware that VLC can do some (all?) of this but it's looks to complicated for my 6year old to use.

Ideally I'd like something ["Air Video Server"](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/index.html) but for mac/win computers with a native client for browsing the movies on the PC running as server.

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:
http://tversity.com/

I use this to stream content to xBox / PS3 / Mac Mini from my Windows 7 Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **Windows Media Player 12** on the server.  You can browse media on the server with any other Windows 7 (or Server 2008 R2) machine using WMP12 as a client, and it should also work with any [**DLNA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA) compliant media players, which include the Digital Media Controller role.

[**List of DLNA-Certified Software.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA#DLNA-Certified_Software)

Comment: Unfortunately I still have some windows-xp computers

Comment: @Nifle: You can use WMP11 as client when WMP12 is the server and the link I gave you lists other third party DLNA certified media players.